# UITableView image causes crash

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I've done a million UITables - with subtitles, images, backgrounds, colors, text-styles - you name it. 
Suddenly, I'm crashing on this table, specifically on the line that calls for the image of the cell.
Here's the code:

```
// Configure the cell:
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Franklin Gothic Book" size:18];
cell.textLabel.text = [leadershipMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [leadershipSubtitlesMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// And here's the statement that causes the crash:
cell.imageView.image = [leadershipPhotosMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Now, the error I get is this:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcacbc'
```

I know for sure that the statement causing the crash is the

```
cell.imageView.image = ...
```

cause as soon as I comment it out everything works fine.

I've never in my life seen an

```
-[__NSCFConstantString _isResizable]:
```

error.
I've googled it but found very little on it.

Very peculiar.

Anyone out there got any clues?

Comment: What is leadershipPhotosMenu? Is it an array of images?

Comment: How did you store images in "leadershipPhotosMenu" array? May i see what it is?

Comment: sure, here's the code: `leadershipPhotosMenu = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"JohnQ.jpg", @"BillZ.png", nil];`  And those images are in my project - meaning they're in Xcode, part of the bundle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

as mentioned in your comment. the way you save your image is what causes the problem.

try this..

```
leadershipPhotosMenu = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"JohnQ.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"BillZ.png"], nil];
```

the code above will store the images in your mutableArray, That will work but I suggest not to store the images in an array.

you can also solve your problem without storing your images in your array like the code above by doing:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:(NSString*)[leadershipPhotosMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

this error message means your object inside your `leadershipPhotosMenu` is not image, but string

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcacbc'
```

Comment: jesus - total brain-fart. Obviously been staring at screen for way too many hours in a row. I have like 40 tables with images in this very project and I can't see this simple error staring in my face. Obviously time to hit the sack :-) Thanks boys! (and sorry)

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
 cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[leadershipPhotosMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: Correct, this is another alternative you may follow.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the name of the images ad not the images. However imageView has UIImage as its property and not the image name. So make below change.

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[leadershipPhotosMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```